How to create a .dat file using Python?
Using numpy I read the .dat file and got a two dimensional array. Then I changed its values, and I want to create a .dat file containing values from this changed array. Is it possible to do this?
I tried using numpy.save and numpy.savetxt functions, but it creates .csv and .txt files, not .dat

.dat file is a generic file format and extension; meaning depends on context.  np.save writes a numpy specific binary format, essentially a header block plus a copy of the underlying numpy array's data buffer.  .npy is its default extension.  np.savetxt writes a csv style of text - rows and columns with comma (or other) separators.

One way is to use pandas:
Let d be your numpy array
After manipulating data:
Convert your 2D numpy array to pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['a'])

df.to_csv('your_file_name.dat')  # it will be saved at your saved path


to_csv writes a text file, same as the np.savetxt.  Using dat as extension says nothing about the file format.
